# PHP mail keeps giving me undefined index, help?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I have a contact form script, and I added a few fields to it, identical to the rest, but the new variables on submit give 'notices' of undefined index, and the variables do not populate. I grab them POST like this,

```
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$website  = $_POST['website'];
$company  = $_POST['company'];
$addy     = $_POST['addy'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
```

The name, email and phone all work, but website, addy and company do not.

The JavaScript that grabs it looks like so,

```
$.post(action, { 
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        website: $('#website').val(),
        company: $('#company').val(),
        addy: $('#addy').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),

..etc
```

What can cause this? I am unsure what other code would be helpful, thank you.

EDIT TO ADD HTML.

Here is some of the form code in the HTML, I can not see anything I missed..

```
<form method="post" action="send_mail.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

        <fieldset>

        <legend>Please fill in the following form to contact us</legend>

        <label for=name accesskey=U><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /> 

        <br />
        <label for=email accesskey=E><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for=website accesskey=W>Website</label>
        <input name="website" type="text" id="website" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for=company accesskey=C>Company</label>
        <input name="company" type="text" id="company" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for=addy accesskey=A>Address</label>
        <input name="addy" type="text" id="addy" size="30" value="" />
```

Comment: If you're still unsure about the answers below post some of your HTML and we'll tell you where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I just added HTML to the original post.

Comment: I put the complete code, the form HTML, PHP and jQuery together here, if someone does not mind taking a peek.. :)

http://pastie.textmate.org/1012951

Comment: Your JS and PHP look fine to me, you need to add double quotes around your `for` and `accesskey` attributes though.   

Also, I presume you left the closing `</fieldset>` and `</form>` tags and the `#phone` input out by accident?

Comment: Thanks Sam, I added the quotes you mentioned. And yes, a few fields and the end of the form I just did not put in there, as it was getting kinda long ;)
I put the entire code structure, HTML, PHP and JS in the pastie though, did you happen to see that? 

http://pastie.textmate.org/pastes/1012961

Answer (score 2):

If the values is false or empty, the post won't include those variables in the AJAX call. Recommend you to use `isset()` in the PHP to verify the variables are set:

```
$name     = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
etc...
```

### Detailed explanation

If we in javascript (jQuery) has following code:

```
$.post('url',{
  'foo': 'bar',
  'baz': $('#nonexisting_element').val(),
   'qux': 'quux'
},...);
```

An `#nonexisting_element` doesn't exists, it will send following:

```
foo=bar&qux=quux
```

and on the PHP side following will end up in the PHP array:

```
$_POST = array (
    'foo' => 'bar'
    'qux' => 'quux'
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I had just been reading that, but what confuses me about it is that the other, existing fields/variables do not do that..? Why would they work?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you check the OP I updated it with some HTML code. I got all the fields I believe, so I don't see why they would not get set...

Comment: @thatryan if given input field is empty, that field will not be present in the query

Comment: Additionally, using the isset() gets rid of the error yes, but still does not populate the variable. I don't understand why it wont come through...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not send post fields whose value is null. So in your case the error is probably that you don't have fields with the given IDs `website, addy, ...`.

Maybe you forgot to add the id=".." attribute or forgot to change it when copying the old code?

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure I got all the fields though... I updated original post with some of the HTML